# This mail server requires authentication before sending mail from a locally hosted domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I got a Error while sending mail in asp.net c#

The error says

> User not local; please try a different path. The server response was:
>   This mail server requires authentication before sending mail from a
>   locally hosted domain. Please reconfigure your mail client to
>   authenticate before sending mail.

```
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        string SmtpHost = "mail.catertainment.com";
        int port = 25;

        string path = string.Format("{0}{1}", Common.ApplicationVirtualRootUrl, "admin.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//COMMONSETTING/EMAILSETTING");
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            SmtpHost = node.SelectSingleNode("SMTP_HOST").InnerText;
            port = Convert.ToInt32(node.SelectSingleNode("SMTP_PORT").InnerText);
        }

        int i = 0;
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("dhasarathan@***.com", "Dhasarathan");
        for (i = 0; i < toAddresses.Length; i++)
        {
            mailMessage.To.Add(toAddresses[i]);
        }
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.Body = body;
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        if (ccAddresses != null)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < ccAddresses.Length; i++)
            {
                mailMessage.CC.Add(ccAddresses[i]);
            }
        }
        if (bccAddresses != null)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < bccAddresses.Length; i++)
            {
                mailMessage.Bcc.Add(bccAddresses[i]);
            }
        }
        SmtpClient smtpClient = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SmtpHost) && port != 0)
            smtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpHost, port);
        else
            smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;           
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("erp@******.com", "*****");           
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        result = "Success";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = "Failure due to " + ex.Message;
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: fromaddress wil come from paramater like dhasarathan@****.com

Comment: is the user in your `fromAddress` an actual email account on the smtp server?

Comment: yes bro it come from actual email account

Comment: Message says that it is not valid in your smtp domain please specify user name and password for login for smtp client

Comment: bro username and password is correct bro

Comment: Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

Comment: Have you ever resolved it @Dhasarathan? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: Try like this smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;